# Readonly<Promise<ListClusters>> Should I still use await?

Tags: typescript, promise, readonly, sonarlint

I have a method that returns  `Readonly<Promise<ListClusters>>`

I use SonarLint that triggers the warning `SonarLint: Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise.`

But I am feeling that's a false positive. Is it correct? If yes, how to correct SonarLint without silencing the warning entirely?

What is the role of `Readonly` here?

Comment: Seems like a shortcoming of the analyzer. A readonly promise is still a promise that can and normally should be awaited. Without the await, you won't get the result you expect, depending on what the code does.

Comment: Please show the actual code related to this warning.  Not only the specific line of code causing the warning, but also the code around it and the function it is referencing.

Comment: @jfriend00 no, `Readonly` is the util type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you running?